# Отправка сообщения Discord bot каждых 24 часа

Tags: python, бот, discord, discord.py

**Написал бота для отправки сообщения каждых 24 часа, бот отправляет одно сообщения после 100 секунд нету следующего сообщения**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

async def background_task():
      time = 100
#86400
      await asyncio.sleep(time)
      await bot.get_channel(*****).send("message")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot logged as {}'.format(bot.user))



token = '*******'
bot.loop.create_task(background_task())
bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

async def background_task():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    
    while not bot.is_closed():
        await bot.get_channel(*****).send("message")
        time = 100
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
          
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot logged as {}'.format(bot.user))

token = '*******'
bot.loop.create_task(background_task())
bot.run(token)
```